# Apache Apex vs Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, stream-processing, apache-apex

As both are streaming frameworks which processes event at a time, What are the core architectural differences between these two technologies/streaming framework?

Also, what are some particular use cases where one is more appropriate than the other?

Answer (score 9):

As you mentioned both are streaming platform which to in memory computation in real time. But there are some architectural differences when you take a closer look.

1. Apex is yarn native architecture, it fully utilises yarn for scheduling, security & multi-tenancy where as Flink integrates with yarn. Apex can do resource allocation at operator (container) level with yarn.
2. Partitioning: Apex supports several sophisticated stream partitioning schemes and also allows controlling operator locality & stream locality. Flink supports simple hash partitions and custom partitions.
3. Apex allows dynamic changes to topology without having to take down the application. Apex allows the application to be updated at runtime so you can add and remove operators, update properties of operators, or automatically scale the application at runtime. Apache Flink does not support any of these capabilities.
4. Buffer Server: There is a message bus called buffer server between operators. Subscribers can connect to buffer server and fetch data from particular offsets. This is window aware, and holds data as long as no subscriber needs it.
5. Fault tolerance: Apex has incremental recovery model, on failure it can  only part of topology can be restarted no need to go back to source, where in flink it goes back to source.
6. Apex has high level api as well as low level api. Flink only has high level api.
7. Apex has a library called Apache Malhar which has vast variety of well tested connectors and processing operators which can be reused easily.
8. Lastly Apex is more focused on productizing big data applications so has many features which will help in easy development and maintenance of applications.

Note: I am a committer to Apache Apex, so I might sound biased to Apex :)

Comment: your note was not needed :-) ... it did sound biased (which is different from untrue) and I could see that you have an axe to grind. What is Flink better at?